# Multiply a Sum column with another column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datagridview

I want a SQL code to grab `Product_name,Sum(quantity),price` from database and show it to datagridview on winform. Until now I have this code to get the data:

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Prod_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity, Price FROM Fatur GROUP BY Prod_name, Price ", conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
conn.Close();
```

Question 1 is: how to add another column on the SQL code that **Multiply** `Sum(quantity) * Price AS Total` ?

I tried another way that fills *dataGridView1* with above code and create another column in *dataGridView1* that multiply column of *quantity* and *price*. Here is the code

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value));
}
```

But it shows a empty column.

Comment: Why not do it in SQL? `SUM(quantity) * Price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better do it in SQL:

```
SELECT Prod_name,
  SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
  Price,
  SUM(quantity) * Price total
FROM Fatur
GROUP BY Prod_name,
  Price;
```

OR:

```
SELECT prod_name,
  quantity,
  price,
  quantity * price total
FROM
  (SELECT Prod_name,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
    Price
  FROM Fatur
  GROUP BY Prod_name,
    Price
  );
```

Comment: I fell so fool rite now..i tried this code yesterday and it didnt worked..now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the calculated column in your query like :

```
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Prod_name, SUM(quantity) AS quantity, Price,SUM(quantity)*Price as Total FROM Fatur GROUP BY Prod_name, Price ", conn);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 conn.Close();
```